# How to display sequence of images using ImageMagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagick

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $im = new imagick('fileuploads/filename.pdf['.$i.']');
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo $im;
}
```

The above code displays only the first page of the PDF file.

Comment: What else do you expect from this code?

Comment: I was expecting the first two pages of the file. What should I do for that??

Comment: You want an image containing the first two pages of your pdf ? or want two images shown one after the other?

Comment: See I want the users of my site to view a PDF in android without downloading it, so to make that work I used imagick to display a preview image instead of the actual pdf, but the problem is that if the PDF file consists of more than 1 page, I am not able to preview the pages other than the first using imagick. So anything that will allow me to preview all the pages of the PDF file, will do.

Comment: I see but one url can send only one image you cannot send images one by one, anyway try code below.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP allows only one resource per url so when visits your preview url he can only see one image like *http://example.com/a.jpg* would open only **a.jpg** it cannot open **b.jpg** at the same time.so your only option is to create a big image and copy the pdf pages you want to show in the preview.I am not sure but you may try the code below

```
$startPage  = 0; // from where to start
$countPages = 1; // how many pages

$pdf = '/pdf/mypdf.pdf[' . $startPage .'-'. $countPages . ']';

$image = new Imagick($pdf);
$image->resizeImage( 400, (($countPages-$startPage)+1)*400, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0);
$image->setImageFormat( "jpg" );

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
```

Comment: nope, didn't go that well. Thanks for trying though.